# How to get a re-formatted json object after looping over it and making asynchronous promise calls

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, promise, google-translate

Not sure if the question is right or wrong. Let me just describe the problem for a better understanding. Consider a multi-level json object with keys having random english text strings as their values. The task is to iterate over the object and visit every node to create another equivalent object containing translated texts for those english strings having same keys (and level) with same parent object as before. Using recursions the translation is working, however from within a promise it is never returning the final translated object. There are no errors though.

**Object:**

```
var obj =   {
  "MENU": {
    "NODE": "Wait for her",
    "RESPONSE": {
      "ATTR": "We'll meet again",
      "SEMANTICS": "The Dark Knighthood"
    }
  },
  "NODES": {
    "STANDARDLIBRARY": {
      "SERVER": "Never say never again",
      "CATEGORIES":{
        "INFOPROTECTION":"Infoprotection",
        "DATAMOTION":"Data In Motion",
        "LOGGING":"Loggin is key to debugging",
        "VERACITY": "Help me understand the best I can",
        "VARIETY": "Silver surfer"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**Code:**

```
const iterateAttributesAndParseJSON = (o) => {
  return new Promise(
   function (resolve, reject) {
      for(var a in o) {
        if (typeof o[a] == 'object'){
          iterateAttributesAndParseJSON(o[a])
        }else{
          if( o[a] != '' ) {
            translate(o[a], {from: 'en', to: 'nl'}).then( res => {
                //return jsonObj[a]=res.text;
                jsonObj[a]=res.text;
                //console.log(jsonObj);
                resolve(jsonObj);
            }).catch(err => {
              console.error(err)
                reject(err);
            });
          }
        }
      }
     }
   );
}

iterateAttributesAndParseJSON(obj).then(asd => { console.log(`Resolved:`,  asd) }, err => console.log(err))
```

Note: Translate is again thenable. I used this npm module.
[google-translate-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api)

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but after the call to translate you are immediately calling return.  Doesn't that mean that the next three lines won't get executed (including resolve()) ?

Comment: Please check now. In the original code the return was commented. I opened it mistaken while pasting it here.

Comment: The only think I can figure out at this point is that after the recursive call  you are not resolving it.  For me I don't get any output  'Resolved', only console logs inside the function.  But it's late here and I gotta pack it in for the day. Best of luck, I might look at it tomorrow because the problem is interesting.

Comment: Mmm, not sure but won't `resolve(jsonObj);` do the job?

Comment: it won't by itself, because that would resolve too soon, but that's where I am at.  Out of curiosity, can you send the translation service an array of strings  to translate at once or does it have to be string by string.  You are making a lot of calls.

Comment: I have found another npm module that will probably enable me to do that.
:translate-json-object
However, this problem seems intriguing to me. I need to check out this npm modules codebase to see how they are managing things. I am just not being able to get my head around asynchronicity.

Comment: @SmokingSheriff modified your code and used promise all, see it works for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of promise all and get the work done, not optimized code but works.

```
    const translate = require('google-translate-api');

    //var jsonObj = {};

    var obj = {
        "MENU": {
            "NODE": "Wait for her",
            "RESPONSE": {
                "ATTR": "We'll meet again",
                "SEMANTICS": "The Dark Knighthood"
            }
        },
        "NODES": {
            "STANDARDLIBRARY": {
                "SERVER": "Never say never again",
                "CATEGORIES": {
                    "INFOPROTECTION": "Infoprotection",
                    "DATAMOTION": "Data In Motion",
                    "LOGGING": "Loggin is key to debugging",
                    "VERACITY": "Help me understand the best I can",
                    "VARIETY": "Silver surfer"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var promises = [];

    const iterateAttributesAndParseJSON = (o) => {
        for (var a in o) {
            if (typeof o[a] == 'object') {
                iterateAttributesAndParseJSON(o[a]);
            } else {
                if (o[a] != '') {
                    var promise = translate(o[a], { from: 'en', to: 'nl' }).then(res => {
                        var jsonObj = {};
                        jsonObj[a] = res.text;
                        return jsonObj;
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.error(err)
                        // reject(err);
                    });
                    promises.push(promise);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    iterateAttributesAndParseJSON(obj);
    console.log(promises.length);

    Promise.all(promises).then(asd => { console.log(`Resolved:`, asd) }, err => console.log(err))
```

Will print the array of key and translations, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it a bit.  I would use a very different design for this.  It is much simpler, doesn't need Promisses and should only require one network call

```js
var obj =   {
  "MENU": {
    "NODE": "Wait for her",
    "RESPONSE": {
      "ATTR": "We'll meet again",
      "SEMANTICS": "The Dark Knighthood"
    }
  },
  "NODES": {
    "STANDARDLIBRARY": {
      "SERVER": "Never say never again",
      "CATEGORIES":{
        "VERACITY": "Help me understand the best I can",
        "VARIETY": "Silver surfer"
      }
    }
  }
};

var vals = [];
shadow = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( obj ));
function traverse(obj, shadow, vals, cb) {
    if (typeof obj == 'object')
        for (var i in obj)
            if (typeof obj[i] == 'object')
                traverse(obj[i], shadow[i], vals, cb);
            else
                cb(i, obj, shadow, vals);
    else
        return false;
}

//setup shadow and array of values
traverse(obj, shadow, vals, function(key, o, s, v) {
    v.push(o[key]);
    s[key] = v.length - 1;
});

function callService( cb ) {
    console.log('... calling translation service... please wait..');
    setTimeout( function() {
        //call translation Service HERE use array vals if service accepts arrays
        // or vals.join(DELIM); where DELIM is something you know the service won't touch
        cb(vals.map( function(v) {return v + '-translated'}));
    }, 1000);
}

callService( function(translatedArr) {
    traverse(obj, shadow, vals, function(key, o, s, v) {
        o[key] = translatedArr[s[key]];
    });
    console.log( obj );
});
```

Please let me know if you like it.